# save IGeometry to disk as a Layer file

Tags: arcgis-engine, c#, arcobjects

How can I save an IGeometry to disk as a Layer file?

ArcEngine 10, C#, VS2010

Edit 1: With Jason Scheirer 's suggestion I managed to convert a point into a shapefile - and I'll post the code here for the community.

```
string strFolder = @"C:\temp";
string strName = "NewShapeFile"; //don't include .shp extension
string strShapeFieldName = "Shape";
ShapefileWorkspaceFactory pWorkspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass();
IFeatureWorkspace pFWS = pWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(strFolder, 0) as IFeatureWorkspace; 
IFields pFields = new FieldsClass();
IFieldsEdit pFieldsEdit = pFields as IFieldsEdit;
IField pField = new FieldClass();
IFieldEdit pFieldEdit = pField as IFieldEdit;
pFieldEdit.Name_2 = strShapeFieldName;  //Name is read-only Name_2 is writeable -- don't ask me why
pFieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry; 
IGeometryDef pGeomDef = new GeometryDefClass();
IGeometryDefEdit pGeomDefEdit = pGeomDef as IGeometryDefEdit;
pGeomDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint;
pGeomDefEdit.SpatialReference_2 = CrowWingCoordinates;
pFieldEdit.GeometryDef_2 = pGeomDef;
pFieldsEdit.AddField(pField);
pField = new FieldClass();
pFieldEdit = pField as IFieldEdit;
pFieldEdit.Length_2 = 25;
pFieldEdit.Name_2 = "TextField";
pFieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString;
pFieldsEdit.AddField(pField);
IFeatureClass pFeatClass = pFWS.CreateFeatureClass(strName, pFields, null, null, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, strShapeFieldName, "");
IFeatureBuffer fb = pFeatClass.CreateFeatureBuffer();
IFeature feature = pFeatClass.CreateFeature(); 
IFeatureCursor featureCursor = pFeatClass.Insert(true);
double x = -94.105797; 
double y = 46.559214; 
IPoint p = new PointClass(); 
p.SpatialReference = gcs;
p.PutCoords(x, y); 
p.Project(myCoordinates); 
IGeometry geometry = p as IGeometry;
fb.Shape = p;
featureCursor.InsertFeature(fb);
featureCursor.Flush();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A layer file does not hold any geographic data -- all it contains is pointers to data sources and symbology. You will need to save your `IGeometry` to disk as a Feature Class. If you then get the `IName` for the feature class, you could open a layer file on disk, *point* to that feature class and save a copy back out.

Workflow:

1. Create new feature class (shapefile)
2. Write your geometry to it with an Insert Cursor
3. Open layer file with predefined symbology
4. Set its root `ILayer`'s data source to `IName` of the shapefile
5. Turn on relative paths in the layer file
6. Save a copy out to the same directory as the shapefile

The superior alternative is to use a layer package with the [Package Layer tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000q4000000.htm).