# Editing shapefile in ArcMap programmatically?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#

Is this something that can be done?

For instance if I created an overlay on a map and saved it as a shapefile, I want to go and edit this (**pre-existing file.**) overlay... Either add points/remove points change color/fillstyle/etc.

Ideally I want to avoid creating a new shapefile and deleting the old one.

Thoughts?

Edit 1:  OK, now that someone has said it can be done.  The obvious question is, how do you edit the shapefile (in ArcObjects pro-grammatically)?

Edit 2: Looking at comments it appears I need to do something like this, but I'm not sure.

I currently have a basic shapefile that I want to edit in ArcObjects in C#.

I've created a shapefile by creating a FeatureClass , Workspace and then obviously passing in my shape.  In this case it's just a simple Polyline with a few points on it.  What I'd like to do is have the ability to update this shapefile.

I'm assuming I need to re-use that FeatureClass, Workspace and pass in a new shape.  However, what I'm doing doesn't seem to work.  This is where I'm at on the edit - any advice would be great.

```
IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = (IWorkspaceEdit)inWorkspace;
workspaceEdit.StartEditing(true);
workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();

ComReleaser comReleaser = new ComReleaser();

IFeatureCursor featureCursor = inFeatureClass.Update(null , true);

IFeature feature = null;
while((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
{
   int id = feature.Fields.FindField("shape");
   IFeatureBuffer featureBuffer = inFeatureClass.CreateFeatureBuffer();
   featureCursor.DeleteFeature(); //Delete the old 
   featureBuffer.Shape = (IGeometry)inShape;
   featureCursor.InsertFeature(featureBuffer);
}

workspaceEdit.StopEdidtOperation();
workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
```

EDIT 3:
*Final Solution*

```
featureCursor = inFeatureClass.Update(null ,true);
//DELETE old shape
featureCursor = inFeatureClass.Insert(true);
//Insert new 
workspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
```

Comment: Are you saying that you drew some annotation layers on the map with ArcMap's drawing tools?  If you converted that to a shape file, you can definitely edit it as if it were a shapefile.

Comment: I'm using the ArcMap.TrackPolygon to create an IPolygon and then I eventually turn that into a shape file.

What I want to do then is edit this shapefile....I know how to get the properties (points, fillstyle, color, etc)

Comment: So in ArcObjects pro-grammatically?

Comment: Yes that's what I'd like to do

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, fyi if you tag with C# you will get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created and manipulated a shapefile programmatically - so maybe this can provide some hints for adding points: [save IGeometry to disk as a Layer file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6868/save-igeometry-to-disk-as-a-layer-file)

As for coloring a layer, that's pretty simple.

```
IGeoFeatureLayer geolayer = thislayer as IGeoFeatureLayer;
ISimpleRenderer simplerenderer = geolayer.Renderer as ISimpleRenderer;
if (simplerenderer != null)
{
//depending on the type one of these objects will probably not be null -- then set .Color and .Symbol 

IMarkerSymbol markersymbol = simplerenderer.Symbol as IMarkerSymbol;
ILineSymbol linesymbol = simplerenderer.Symbol as ILineSymbol;
SimpleFillSymbol simpleFillSymbol = simplerenderer.Symbol as SimpleFillSymbol;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I'm not wording this question correctly.  I can already create and save a shape file programmatically .

What I want to do is edit this pre-existing file.  I'm guessing the same logic will work though....

Comment: @PSU_Kardi I think you have to use featureCursor.InsertFeature(fb); and featureCursor.DeleteFeature to edit your pre-existing file

Comment: I'll look into it - I think that's what I want